# Prevent IDE0055 style analyzer when aligning code with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn-code-analysis

I use a very common formatting technique that improves readability, by aligning code.

e.g. 1 with declarations (possible via [`csharp_space_around_declaration_statements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#csharp_space_around_declaration_statements))

```cs
var a    = foo;
var bc   = 123;
var some = thing;
```

e.g. 2 not with declarations

```cs
a    = foo;
bc   = 123;
some = thing;
```

But I'm using the roslyn analyzers, and that triggers `IDE0055:Fix formatting` (for the first two lines).

In `.editorconfig`, is there a `dotnet_xxx` or `csharp_xxx` config option (or combination) that allows this style?

Comment: I also used to be a big fan of "tabular code formatting" while I was working alone.  But when you work together with others, it is a very bad idea, because it causes merge conflicts.  So, I had to abandon it.  Great feature; don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = ignore` in `.editorconfig`

This setting is located in `Text editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Spacing -> ignore spaces in declaration statements`

Although I don't know a way to disable autoformat in pattern matching:

```cs
static int Foo(int x, int y) => (x, y) switch
{
    (    0,     0) => 0,
    (int i,     0) => 11,
    (int i, int j) => i + j,
};
```

Comment: For completeness, in vscode it's at: `.vscode/.editorconfig`

Comment: This works nicely for delcarations, it's unfortunate it doesn't work in non-declaration statements (e.g. same as my example above, but without `var`). Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @lonix, I don't any any possibility to achieve that

Comment: I added a request [to the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/51389) that includes your case.